# Java POI SS Usermodel conversion

Tags: java, apache-poi

Helo all Is there a `page` for the sheet in the new SS model??

I cant seem to find it...my old code was like this:

```
   Footer footer = sheet.getFooter();
        footer.setCenter( "(UNCLASSIFIED) Page " + Footer.page() + " of " + Footer.numPages() );
```

I cant see to find Footer.page() or Footer.numPages() in the new model SS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Umm, you're already using the org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel code there... See the [ss.usermodel.Footer javadocs](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Footer.html)

If you were still on HSSF, you'd be calling HSSFFooter, the fact that you're calling Footer not HSSFFooter / XSSFFooter tells you you're on the new interfaces

Comment: Using the ss model...I have to use HeaderFooter for those methods .page(), etc....